# Adding Rows To DataGridView, only one row shows up?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
foreach (var a in A)
{
    dataGridMain.Rows.Add();
    dataGridMain.Rows[dataGridMain.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = a.Date;
    dataGridMain.Rows[dataGridMain.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = a.Value;
}
```

When I run the loop above, it adds all of the rows but only the last row contains any data.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does Rows.Count changes during the loop ?

Comment: what is an `A`? Does `a.Date` have a value?

Comment: @Dani, each time I'm doing dataGridMain.Rows.Add(); so I'm assuming the row count changes

Comment: @Hunter, A just is a list of data objects, yes a.Date has a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the index from Add in case it is doing something hokey with ordering:

```
var index = grid.Rows.Add();
grid.Rows[index].Cells[....
```

Or better:

```
var index = grid.Rows.Add();
var row = grid.Rows[index];
row.Cells[....
row.Cells[....
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try and see if this works?

```
foreach(var a in A)
{
  YourObject row = new YourObject(){a.Date, a.Value};
  dataGridMain.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index doesnt change.
You state dataGridMain.Rows.Count -1 as an index

It looks like the count does not change, it appears you need to grab the index first, store it in a variable and then add the values:

`int n = dataGridMain.Rows.Add();`

`//now use n`

`dataGrid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = a.date;`

`//more code`

Comment: But the count changes as far as I can see. Was my first guess, too, but I think this isn't the issue.

Comment: @Anne Schuessler - The count index changes so you have to return the index to a variable (in this case integer).  I posted an example.

Answer (score 0):

dataGridMain.Rows.Add(); Does this adds the rows to bottom or adds it to the first.
If it adds it at the begininning then you are just adding new record but updating the same record all the time.